# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 linked command exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error when building for the simulator:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SA_OAuthTwitterEngine", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NetworkUpdateViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SA_OAuthTwitterController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NetworkUpdateViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MGTwitterEngine", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterLoginViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And this one when building for the local device (iPad):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SA_OAuthTwitterController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NetworkUpdateViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SA_OAuthTwitterEngine", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NetworkUpdateViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MGTwitterEngine", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterLoginViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Tried everything I can think of... can you help me?

Comment: What did you think of? And what did you try?

Comment: so, what _did_ it say when you added `-v` to the compile flags?

Answer (score 4):

Clang is pretty good about putting errors in human readable plain text, it's just that we sometimes look at the big picture and give up.  Look here:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SA_OAuthTwitterController"
```

Now strip away the standard _OBJC_CLASS_$ part and what do you get?  `SA_OAuthTwitterController`.

Now, the second part:

```
... referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NetworkUpdateViewController.o
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SA_OAuthTwitterEngine", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NetworkUpdateViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MGTwitterEngine", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in TwitterLoginViewController.o
```

Obviously, you are ***referencing*** this non-existent header ***in*** ***classes named***: `NetworkUpdateViewController`, and `TwitterLoginView`.

Now at this point, two possibilities come up:  either this is you not adding the right files to the Compile Sources list, or you happen to be using a framework that wasn't built for the iOS Simulator (architecture i386) (or a universal library, as they are often called).  In case one, find the offending implementation files and drag them to the Compile Sources list then build and run.  If case number two, then you must test on a device, or try to recompile the lib into a useable universal library, which is tougher than it sounds.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Did (1) already, but it didn't work. Now worked on (2), recomp lib. - and finally the build succeeded!